# Verify if 2 textbox are empty when a user selects a combobox

Tags: vba, textbox

I am creating a VBA form which has 2 textboxes and 1 combobox.
[image]

I would like to create the following condition.
When the user tries to change the combobox value without having put the amount in the 2 textbox first.
I would like to display a message e.g. "The textboxes need to have values", not allowing the user to continue.

```vb
Sub TextBoxnull()
         
    If Len(TextBoxnull.txtTOPDtotalrem.Value) = 0 And Len(TextBoxnull.txtTOPDmedical.Value) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Number must be entered to continue!"
    End If
    TextBoxnull.cboTOPDsuperannuationperc.Value = Format(TextBoxnull.cboTOPDsuperannuationperc.Value, "0%")
    Sheet1.Range("B10").Value = Format(TextBoxnull.cboTOPDsuperannuationperc.Value, "0%")
    With TextBoxnull
        .txtTOPtaxableremexclsuperannuation.Value = Format(Sheet1.Range("B13").Value, "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00")
        .txtTOPsuperannuationcontribution.Value = Format(Sheet1.Range("B14").Value, "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00")
        .txtTOPDtotalremnet.Value = Format(Sheet1.Range("B15").Value, "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00")
    End With
            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It's an even procedure that will run when the user clicks on the Combobox. You would have to replace the control names with the ones you used in your form.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()

    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim Tbx     As MSForms.TextBox
    
    Set Tbx = TextBox1
    For i = 1 To 2
        With Tbx
            If Len(Trim(.Value)) = 0 Then
                .SetFocus
                MsgBox "Please enter a value in the selected Text Box."
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
        Set Tbx = TextBox2
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you just want to test the code, create a form with 2 TextBoxes called TextBox1 and TextBox2 and one Combobox called ComboBox1, as the procedure's name indicates.

Comment: Hello @Variatus Thanks for your input. I call this procedure if a user select the combobox without adding the values in the 2 textbox

Comment: You don't call this procedure. It is called automatically when the user clicks on the ComboBox. If the two text boxes are filled nothing will happen but if one of the is empty it will be select and a message shown.

Answer (score 0):

@variatus...

I made the changes, but it is not working. I am new in VBA and I am not sure if i am doing something wrong...

## Here is I call the procedure

```
Private Sub cboTOPDsuperannuationperc_Change()
   Call m_TopDown.Taxableremexclsuperannuation1
End Sub
```

This is the code with my changes based on my form.
Sub Taxableremexclsuperannuation1()

```
Dim i       As Integer
Dim Tbx     As MSForms.TextBox

Set Tbx = frmTaxablepay.txtTOPDtotalrem
For i = 1 To 2
    With Tbx
        If Len(Trim(.Value)) = 0 Then
            .SetFocus
            MsgBox "Please enter a value in the selected Text Box."
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
    Set Tbx = frmTaxablepay.txtTOPDmedical
Next i
```

End Sub